# How to separate different nature records into different dataframes

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like this:

[image: dataframe data set]

The first 2 records have 4 columns (`+` is the delimiter) and last 2 records have 5 columns.

How to move these records into 2 dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using regex (`rlike`)

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([('q+w+e+r',), ('q+w+e+r+t',)], ['Col_Explode'])

df2 = df.filter(F.col('Col_Explode').rlike(r'^([^+]+\+){3}[^+]+$'))
df3 = df.filter(F.col('Col_Explode').rlike(r'^([^+]+\+){4}[^+]+$'))

df.show()
# +-----------+
# |Col_Explode|
# +-----------+
# |    q+w+e+r|
# |  q+w+e+r+t|
# +-----------+
df2.show()
# +-----------+
# |Col_Explode|
# +-----------+
# |    q+w+e+r|
# +-----------+
df3.show()
# +-----------+
# |Col_Explode|
# +-----------+
# |  q+w+e+r+t|
# +-----------+
```